Why is Method $1$ incorrect?
Question:
An unbiased cubical die is thrown $n$ times. If $x_i=$ outcome on the $ith$ throw and $X=gcd\{x_1,x_2,...x_n\}$ then $E(X)$ is equal to
$(1)\frac1{6^n}(6^n+3^n+2^n)$
$(2)\frac1{6^n}(6^n+3^n+2^n+1)$
$(3)\frac1{6^n}(6^n+3^n+2^{n+1}+8)$
$(4)\frac1{6^n}(6^n+3^n+2^{n+2}+8)$
Method$1$:
If $X=6$, then we should get $6$ on all throws. So, prob=$\frac1{6^n}$
If $X=5$, then we should get $5$ on all throws. So, prob=$\frac1{6^n}$
If $X=4$, then we should get $4$ on all throws. So, prob=$\frac1{6^n}$
If $X=3$, then we should get at least one $3$ and rest can be $3$ or $6$. So, prob=$n\frac16(\frac26)^{n-1}$
If $X=2$, then we should get at least one $2$ and rest can be $2$ or $4$ or $6$. So prob=$n\frac16(\frac36)^{n-1}$
If $X=1$, then prob=$1-$above cases.
In the options above, $n$ is only in the power, but I am getting in multiplication as well. So, this method must be wrong.
Method $2$:
If $X=3$, we need at least one $3$ and rest throws could be $3$ or $6$, so, prob= cases with $3$ or $6$ $-$ cases where there is no $3=(\frac26)^n-(\frac16)^n$
If $X=2$, we need at least one $2$ and rest throws could be $2$ or $4$ or $6$, so, prob= cases with $2$ or $4$ or $6$ $-$ cases where there is just $4$ or just $6=(\frac36)^n-2(\frac16)^n$
Using this approach, I am getting option $3$, which matches with the given answer.
My doubt: why is method $1$ incorrect?
My Attempt:
In method $2$ for $X=3$, when I write, $(\frac26)^n-(\frac16)^n$, it ensures that we get a case where, say, there are two $3's$ and rest $6's$.
But in method $1$ for $X=3$, when I write $n\frac16(\frac26)^{n-1}$, does that ensure we get a case where there are exactly two $3's$ and rest $6's$? We are surely getting one $3$, but others can be $3$ or $6$. But if others can be $3$ or $6$, does that not mean we would get a case where we would get atleast one more $3$ and other $6's$?
I don't know I am feeling confused.
Also, in case of binomial trials, when we write $^nC_rp^rq^{n-r}$ then $p$ and $q$ sums upto $1$. But in my case, $\frac16$ and $\frac26$ don't sum upto $1$.
How to ensure that I don't repeat this error next time?

Your computations of $P(X=3)$ and of $P(X=2)$ are wrong. You're miscounting the configurations where more than one of the $x_i$ are equal to $3$ (respectively $2$). They should both just be $(2/6)^n-(1/6)^n$ (the draws from ${3,6}$, minus the one that is constant $6$).

The way not to make mistakes is to always do the correct answer.

One problem with both methods is that $\gcd(4,6)=2$, so there is no need to get a $2$ at all to have $X=2$. You do need to exclude the cases where only $4$s are rolled or only $6$s are rolled, but that's it.
The bigger problem with Method $1$ is that it massively overcounts configurations. To see the problem, consider $n=5$ in the $X=3$ case. Is the sequence $3,\ 6,\ 3,\ 3,\ 6$ a sequence where roll $1$ was the mandatory $3$ and rolls $3$ and $4$ were rolls that just happened to come up $3$? Or is roll $3$ the mandatory $3$? Or roll $4$? This configuration gets counted three times by your formula in Method $1$. In general, the degree of overcounting of a sequence will depend on the number of $3$s it contains. And the degree of overcounting will tend to get worse as $n$ gets bigger.
In the end you give the correct formula for the $X=2$ case in Method $2$, but your formula doesn't match your description. Actually, you give two inconsistent descriptions, and it doesn't match the first of those: "we need at least one $2$ and rest throws could be $2$ or $4$ or $6$". If you had really followed that description, you would have ended up with $\left(\tfrac{3}{6}\right)^n-\left(\tfrac{2}{6}\right)^n$ instead of $\left(\tfrac{3}{6}\right)^n-2\left(\tfrac{1}{6}\right)^n$.
About your last question,

Also, in case of binomial trials, when we write $^nC_rp^rq^{n-r}$ then $p$ and $q$ sums upto $1$. But in my case, $\frac16$ and $\frac26$ don't sum upto $1$.

it might be sensible to use this formula in certain situations where $p$ and $q$ don't add to $1$. The problem with applying this formula in your situation is not that $p$ and $q$ don't add to $1$, but that they are probabilities for non-disjoint sets of possibilities: rolling a $3$ overlaps with rolling a $3$ or a $6$, which is giving rise to your overcounting.

What a wonderful answer! Explanations like this are the reasons why I come to this website. Thanks!
